# Oracle JDBC Driver inserting wrong data.

Tags: oracle, jdbc, unicode, multibyte

The following is a very simple JDBC Insert of literal SQL strings which is resulting in invalid data.

This is the table used for the Insert into the Oracle DB.

```
create table test_nls (Field1 varchar2(100));
```

This is the Java code.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JDBCBatchUpdateExample {

        private static final String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
//      private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.190.1:1521/orcl";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:oci:scott/tiger@orcl";

        private static Properties props = new Properties();

        public static void main(String[] argv) {

                try {
                        batchInsertRecordsIntoTable();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
        }

        private static void batchInsertRecordsIntoTable() throws SQLException
        {
                props.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals", "true");
                Connection dbConnection = null;
                Statement statement = null;
                String insertTableSQL1 = "INSERT INTO TEST_NLS (Field1) values ('Hello World')";

                String insertTableSQL2 = "INSERT INTO TEST_NLS (Field1) values ('3£333££')";

                try {
                        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
                        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
                        statement.addBatch(insertTableSQL1);
                        statement.addBatch(insertTableSQL2);
                        statement.executeBatch();
                        dbConnection.commit();
                        System.out.println("Records are inserted");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                              statement.close();
                                dbConnection.close();
                }
        }

        private static Connection getDBConnection() {
                Connection dbConnection = null;
                try {
                        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                try {
                        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, props);
                        return dbConnection;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                return dbConnection;
        }
}
```

An attempt was made to see if the following call would help but it did not.

```
 props.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals", "true");
```

The actual file is being provided to me so I can't edit the data to convert to using other work-arounds that I have read.

The data inserted results in the following :

```
 Hello World
 3Ā£333Ā£Ā£
```

Is there some JDBC call I can make to get the Insert to not convert the data?

Comment: What are your OS, JVM and DB character sets?

Comment: Also, is your Java source file saved as a UTF-8 encoded file?

Comment: ... and do you get better results if you use `N'3£333££'` instead of `'3£333££'` ...?

Comment: OS is Linux, JVM is 1.8 and assume using UCS-2 and the Oracle DB characterset is AL32UTF8.   I believe the Java source is saved properly because if I execute the 'cat' command on the file, the data is correct.  Adding 'N' to the front did not do anything.

Comment: Perhaps try `PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TEST_NLS (Field1) values (?)"); ps.setString(1, "3£333££"); ps.executeUpdate();`

Comment: This is a simple sample, the SQL file is sort of fixed and being processed as a string literal without any modifications other than setting any properties or environments.

Comment: @UnhandledException - So this "file" of which you speak is a text file full of SQL statements ("INSERT INTO ...") and not a file of raw data?

Comment: Essentially yes. Each INSERT INTO ...... is read in from a file and executed via JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that each non-ASCII character was being converted into 2 individual characters which is why the resulting size of the data in Oracle was larger.

After much research, I found that by reading in the file using the following code as UTF8, the data is now getting populate as expected.

```
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```